# Android Circular Motion of a Device

Tags: android, accelerometer

What sensor can I use to detect circular motion of an Android device, and how can I detect such motion?  Maybe using the accelerometer?

Comment: Define "circular motion" more precisely.

Comment: like the earth revolving around Sun..@SeanOwen

Comment: The earth spins as it orbits the sun. Maybe you really mean "like a user waving the phone in a circle". It matters, since those motions looks quite different to an accelerometer. So again, you need to say exactly what motion you are detecting to get help on exactly how to detect it.

Comment: @SeanOwen The second one .. user waving a phone in a circle ..

Answer (score 1):

I believe the accelerometer would be able to detect a circular motion.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10477107/629555) talks about detecting the direction of movement on the x-y axis. You could probably use some of the things mentioned there to begin working on detecting a circular motion.

You would absolutely have to record a lot of historical movement to help determine if the device is moving in a circle. If you can determine direction on the x-y axis, you could then determine circular motion on that same axis if you consider the historical direction.

E.g. for clockwise circular motion on the x-y axis.

UP and RIGHT -> DOWN and RIGHT -> DOWN and LEFT ->UP and LEFT

This would give you a circle.