# Android accelerometer use values

Tags: android, android-sensors

I want to detect montion by accelerometer.I found on internet how to init sensor and how to read values. I read values with:
 `Sensors.readSensor(Sensors.SENSOR_ACCELEROMETER, out);`

But how can I use this values to detect montion.How can I detect LIFT UP,LIFT DOWN,MOVE RIGHT,MOVE LEFT,MOVE FORWARD,MOVE BACK,ROTATE LEFT,ROTATE RIGHT,SHAKE and other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever the the position is changed, use

```
onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
```

using the **event** object you can fetch the changed values, and based on that you can decide you motion. Best example for motion detection can be found in the below link:

[How can I get the direction of movement using an accelerometer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476625/how-can-i-get-the-direction-of-movement-using-an-accelerometer/10477107#10477107)