# How to use accelerometer on Android Wear to record rowing stroke

Tags: android, accelerometer, wear-os

My goal is to have a simple stroke rate detector displayed on my Android Watch (Sony Smartwatch), for this I need to detect when the watch changes from moving forwards to moving backwards.

I have code working that will get the event values (x,y,z) as detected in the onSensorChanged event (and display them on the watch), but I am struggling to make sense of these.

I understand the values report acceleration in the given axis, and I understand that z reports gravity. But if these values are reporting just acceleration, I am not clear how to know when there is a change of direction. I presume a positive number indicates acceleration, a number of 0 is a constant speed and a negative number is deceleration...is that correct? And if so, how can I detect when the Watch has changed direction from going forwards to going backwards?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Android Wear is no different than "conventional" Android when it comes to detecting motion. Basically, you need to consider exactly what the accelerometers are recording: raw acceleration (with a **lot** of noise). To determine *motion* from that, you need to look at trends over time, and probably integrate the smoothed accelerometer data. It's not trivial.

You'll probably want to use the `TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION` [sensor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html), because it filters out gravity (which isn't relevant to your use case). And because the watch will probably experience some rotation during a rowing stroke (which you want to factor out), you may need to combine `TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR` with the acceleration vector to accurately determine direction changes.

A couple of other SO questions which may help point you in the right direction:

- [how to calculate phone's movement in the vertical direction from rest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291110)
- [How can I get the direction of movement using an accelerometer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476625)

I've not attempted this specific problem, of course, but I've done enough other work with Android motion sensors to know that you have a good programming challenge ahead of you. Enjoy it!

Comment: Thanks for the input and pointers, wow integration I'm going to have to dust off my very old maths books.